# Javascript arguments passed are smaller than called

Tags: javascript

Currently, Javascript is deducting 2 from the arguments passed in my website.

For example, if I call my function like `myFunction(123, 012)` and then log the values of the arguments in the function, they come out as 123, and 10.  Why does Javascript deduct 2 from my integer values where there is a leading zero?

My function:

```
function myFunction(arg1, arg2){
    console.log("Argument One: " + arg1 + ". Argument Two: " + arg2);
}
```

Comment: *where there is a leading zero*, where is your js function :)

Comment: maybe it would be a good idea to show the function

Comment: Updated with Function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not deducting `2`. `012` is an octal representation, whose value is `10`.

Comment: So then how do I make it not use an octal, and just `012`?

Comment: Convert the argument to string.

Answer (score 1):

In Javascript before EMCA-262 Edition 3, integer literals can be of several types (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals):

- No leading zero: Interpreted as decimal literal (`12` = 12 in decimal)
- Leading zero: octal interpretation (`012` = 10 in decimal)
- Leading 0x: hexadecimal (`0x12` = 18 in decimal)

However, these days octal literals are deprecated (since Javascript 1.5), for exactly the reason shown here, that they are very confusing.

As a side note, it is worth enabling [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/Strict_mode) (add "use strict", with the quotes, to the stop of your code). It would have thrown a syntax error when you loaded the page with this code on.